# Импорт модуля radiusd от freeradius

Tags: python

Использую в своих проектах freeradius с вязкой SQL+FILES модулями, необходимо прикрутить модуль radiusd от freeradius, но никак ладу дать не могу, где его взять, и собрал со строчкой

```
./configure --with-experimental-modules
```

и тут ступор. Кто какие может дать наводки на решение проблемы?

Answer (score 3):

1. Убеждаетесь что FreeRADIUS собран с rlm_python. Как я понимаю, это Вы уже сделали, если нет — уточните в комментариях. Вообще, сборки с experimental modules (rlm_python относится к ним) должно быть достаточно.
2. Прописываете в конфигурации секцию `python` с указанием на Ваш модуль.
3. Дальше, при запуске, FreeRADIUS импортирует Ваш модуль, и из него, в свою очередь, можно будет импортировать `radiusd`.

Пример на пальцах (не проверял, но должно работать с поправкой на возможные опечатки):

В конфигах FreeRADIUS:

```
python {
    mod_instantiate = spam
    func_instantiate = instantiate
    mod_detach = spam
    func_detach = detach
    mod_authorize = spam
    func_authorize = authorize
}
```

Модуль:

```
# spam.py
import radiusd
from decorator import decorator # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator
import re

RADIUS_TYPE_MAP = (
    (re.compile('^"(.*)"$'), lambda m: m.group(1)),
    (re.compile('^(-?\d+)$'), lambda m: int(m.group(1))),
)

def radius_value(value_string):
    """
    Given a FreeRADIUS-provided raw value string, converts it
    to an appropriate type, using the conversion rules defined
    in RADIUS_TYPE_MAP tuple.

    >>> radius_value('"foobar"')
    'foobar'
    >>> radius_value('Wireless-802.11')
    'Wireless-802.11'
    >>> type(radius_value('"foobar"'))
    <type 'str'>
    >>> type(radius_value('-123'))
    <type 'int'>
    """
    if type(value_string) in (str, unicode):
        for regexp, processor in RADIUS_TYPE_MAP:
            m = regexp.match(value_string)
            if m is not None:
                return processor(m)
    return value_string

@decorator
def radius_function(f, params):
    """
    A decorator for convenient type conversion between
    FreeRADIUS proplist-like tuples of pairs and dictionaries.

    I.e., when undecorated function would receive a tuple
    `(('User-Name', '"spam"'), ('NAS-Port', "123"))`, decorated
    one will get an `{'User-Name': 'spam', 'NAS-Port': 123}`.
    """
    data = dict()
    for name, value in params:
        data[name] = radius_value(value)
    try:
        data = f(data)
    except:
        # logger.exception('An exception occured while calling %s', f.__name__)
        return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_FAIL
    if type(data) is tuple:
        res = (data[0],) + tuple(map(lambda d: tuple(d.iteritems()), data[1:]))
    else:
        res = data
    return res

def instantiate(_params):
    radiusd.radlog(radiusd.L_DBG, "spam.py: instantiated")
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK

def detach(_params):
    radiusd.radlog(radiusd.L_DBG, "spam.py: detached")
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK

@radius_function
def authorize(params):
    radiusd.radlog(radiusd.L_AUTH, "spam.py: authorize(%r)" % params)
    if params.get('', None) == 'test':
        return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_UPDATED,      # return code
                {},                              # reply dict
                {'Cleartext-Password': 'test'})  # config dict
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOOP
```

Запускаем `freeradius -X` (отладочный режим) и смотрим на поведение.

Для удобства (скажем, юнит-тестирования — без тестов, когда кода уже много, и приходит время рефакторинга — страшновато ;)) можно сделать свой модуль-обертку для radiusd с какой-то подобной логикой:

```
"""
rlm_python radiusd wrapper.

This module exports everything `radiusd` module has, and provides a "testing" values
(different from real ones) when run "standalone".
"""

try:
    import radiusd
    IS_REAL_RADIUS = True
    for name in dir(radiusd):
        if not name.startswith('_'):
            vars()[name] = getattr(radiusd, name)
except ImportError:
    IS_REAL_RADIUS = False
    for name in ('AUTH', 'CONS', 'DBG', 'ERR', 'INFO', 'PROXY'):
        vars()['L_{0}'.format(name)] = name
    _codes = ('FAIL', 'HANDLED', 'INVALID', 'NOOP', 'NOTFOUND', 'OK', 'REJECT',
              'UPDATED', 'USERLOCK')
    for name in _codes:
        vars()['RLM_MODULE_{0}'.format(name)] = name
    RLM_MODULE_NUMCODES = len(_codes)

    def radlog(level, message):
        """
        Dummy logging function.
        """
        print('radlog> {0}: {1}'.format(level, message))
```

И импортировать, соответственно, не radiusd, а этот модуль, который будет вести себя так же, как и radiusd, но позволит отлаживать и без присутствия FreeRADIUS (н-р, при запуске nose)

**Возможные проблемы:**

1. FreeRADIUS может не хотеть запускаться, жалуясь в духе `undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct`. Проблема вызвана некорректной линковкой с libpython, подпирается костылем-хаком в духе `LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so"`. Более правильное решение — правка мейкфайлов.
2. FreeRADIUS с rlm_python [может не хотеть «умирать» по SIGINT](http://lists.cistron.nl/pipermail/freeradius-devel/2003-June/005160.html) (разработчики сказали «patches welcome» и наплевали). С причиной не разбирался, по SIGKILL мрет как миленький, хотя это и не так удобно.

**Обновление:**

Я добавил в модуль простенькой обвязки (декоратор `radius_function`), пригодной для тестирования CHAP. Все взято из продакшен-кода, но слегка переделано в сторону упрощения (убрано логгирование, профайлинг и мелкие vendor-specific различия, вызванные тем, что мы работаем с патченным rlm_python), так что могут быть какие-то тривиальные опечатки.

Comment: Пытаюсь запустить и в результате
Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/modules/radiusd_test.py[8]: Expecting section start brace '{' after "import radiusd

Comment: FreeRADIUS пытается использовать `radiusd_test.py` как файл конфигурации. Потенциальная причина — директива вида `$INCLUDE modules/` в основном конфиге. Директива правильная, неправильно ложить .py-файл в этот каталог. Переложите его в другое место (при этом убедитесь, что оно будет доступно, скажем, через PYTHONPATH, иначе rlm_python не найдет модуль).

Comment: С этим разобрался еще до твоего ответа, Спасибо!
Вот есть еще одна ошибочка:

Sat Sep 10 13:34:58 2011 : Info: ++[python] returns ok
Sat Sep 10 13:34:58 2011 : Info: ERROR: No authenticate method (Auth-Type) found for the request: Rejecting the user
Sat Sep 10 13:34:58 2011 : Info: Failed to authenticate the user.

Comment: Подозрение, что в authenticate нет нужного Auth-Type. Разбирайтесь с конфигурацией FreeRADIUS. Если не выходит — показывайте выжимку из конфигов (наверное, лучше отдельным вопросом — с rlm_python это уже косвенно связано, да и в этом скоро закончится лимит по комментариям).

Вот упрощенный пример, для простого случая с только CHAP (все остальное, кроме EAP, добавляется так же; с EAP все несколько хитрее). Должно быть что-то в духе:

    ...
    authorize {
        python
        chap
    }
    authenticate {
        Auth-Type CHAP {
            python
            chap
        }
    }
    ...